# Recursive Tree Rewrite ANTLR

Tags: parsing, tree, antlr, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an AST containing a simple list of tokens...

[image]

and I simply want to group pairs of balanced parameters into nested trees.

I've been trying various rules but I can't quite get it...

```
bottomup : findParams;

findParams
: ^(LIST left+=expression* LPARAM inner? RPARAM right+=expression*)
-> ^(LIST  $left* ^(PARAMS inner?) $right*);

inner : (left+=expression* LPARAM inner? RPARAM right+=expression*)
-> $left* ^(PARAMS inner?) $right*) | (a+=expression* -> $a*);

fragment expression = INT;
```

This is sort of like the dyck language, but on a tree rather than a source. Also, I can't debug pattern matching tree grammars using remote debugging which is a hindrance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just posted an answer, and then understood, that it may be not quite you need. Please, explain more detailed, what do you mean: "...but on a tree rather than a source". Does it means, that you can work only with some Tree list, but not with input text (string)?

Comment: Hi, yes I'm working with the AST generated by the parser, and I want to manipulate it using a tree grammar to nest the parameters. The above example is a super-simple version of a possible tree. My actual grammar is much more complex, and doesn't have simple things like INT or even LPARAM/RPARAM.

It's the same problem nonetheless. I guess it is possible, and much better to do this in the parser phase, however it's much simpler in the tree grammar phase.

Comment: Ok. May be this is a stupid suggestion, but... If I would tried to solve this issue, I would do transform input AST into simple string, and then parse it using my own grammar in convenient form for my purposes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is on the right track, but you're mixing a top-down approach with a bottom-up one. Top-down is good for breaking things down: "this list is big, make it into some smaller ones." Bottom-up is good for breaking things *out*: "this is the simplest thing that could be a list, so I'll make it into one."

Here is a bottom-up solution to grouping your nodes:

```
bottomup
    : exit_list
    ;

exit_list
    : ^(LIST pre* LPAR reduced* RPAR post+=.*) -> ^(LIST pre* ^(LIST reduced*) $post*)
    ;

pre : INT
    | LPAR 
    | ^(LIST .*)
    ;   

reduced
    : INT
    | ^(LIST .*)
    ;
```

For each set of parentheses that contains no other parentheses, convert the contents of that set into a new list. This rule is repeated until there are no more parentheses.

Example:

#### Input

```
1(3(4))5
```

#### Baseline AST

[image: baseline AST]

#### Final AST

[image: grouped AST]

Rule `bottomup` was recursively applied twice:

```
applied to (4):    (LIST 1 '(' 3 '(' 4 ')' ')' 5) -> (LIST 1 '(' 3 (LIST 4) ')' 5)

applied to (3(4)): (LIST 1 '(' 3 (LIST 4) ')' 5) -> (LIST 1 (LIST 3 (LIST 4)) 5)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for your suggestion, however I can't get it work. I'm using a custom AST node type, set ASTLabelType and keep getting 'Cannot cast...' exceptions.

Comment: I changed it to CommonTree, and the exceptions disappear, but I can't match nested parameters. If they contain only INTs or surrounded by INTs then it works, but the recursive bit doesnt.

Comment: @DavidJamesBall ANTLR is picky about what it matches in the tree and what it produces from rules, and making a small change to a rule can subtly change either. In my example, if you remove `| ^(LIST .*)` from rule `pre`, it will match the rest as expected, but it won't produce anything at all, just `null` nodes that don't appear in the output. My advice is to break out your matches explicitly into their own rules (e.g., prefer rule `pre` with everything in it over `pre+=.*`). If that doesn't work, consider writing a new question with the details of what isn't matching.

Comment: I decided it was easier to incorporate this matching inside the parser phase instead, however I still have a slight issue...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980501/parse-parenthesis-as-atoms-antlr