# Parse Parenthesis as atoms ANTLR

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, expression

I'm trying to match balanced parentheses such that, a `PARAMS` tree is created if a match is made, else the LPARAM and RPARAM tokens are simply added as atoms to the tree...

```
tokens
{
    LIST;    
    PARAMS;
}

start   : list -> ^(LIST list);

list    : (expr|atom)+;

expr : LPARAM list? RPARAM -> ^(PARAMS list?);

atom :  INT | LPARAM | RPARAM;

INT :   '0'..'9'+;
LPARAM  :   '(';
RPARAM  :   ')';
```

At the moment, it will never create a `PARAMS` tree, because in the rule expr it will always see the end `RPARAM` as an atom, rather than the the closing token for that rule.

So at the moment, something like `1 2 3 (4) 5` is added to a `LIST` tree as a flat list of tokens, rather than the required grouping.

I've handled adding tokens as atoms to a tree before, but they never were able to start another rule, as `LPARAM` does here.

Do I need some sort of syntatic/semantic predicate here?

Comment: Are `LPARAM` and `RPARAM` actually atoms or are they syntactic markers denoting the beginning and end of a list? Is there a case when you want one to be treated as an atom and another case when it should be a marker?

Comment: Yes, LPARAM and RPARAM have the ability to appear in a tree on their own. They're not just syntactic markers.

I want them to be treated as markers, only when it can actually match a parenthesised expression. So in "1 2 (3)", the (3) should be a parenthesised expression and the resulting tree should be ^(LIST 1 2 ^(PARAMS 3)).

Whereas an unsuccessful match such as 1 2 )3) should become ^(LIST 1 2 ) 3 )).

Comment: I see. How should the grammar handle input like " 1 (2) 3)"? Should that be "1 ^(LIST 2) 3 ')'" or "1 ^(LIST 2 ')' 3 )"?

Comment: How about "(1 (2) 3"? Is that "`^(LIST '(' 2) 3`" or "`'(' 1 ^(LIST 2) 3`"?

Comment: The second one. Whenever any part of the string can be successfully balanced by an open and closed parenthesis, then it is created as a PARAMS tree, otherwise it failed and the LPARAM/RPARAM should just added as atoms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple approach that comes with a couple of constraints. I think these conform to the expected behavior that you mentioned in the comments.

- An unmatched `LPARAM` never appears inside a child list
- An unmatched `RPARAM` never appears inside a child list

Grammar:

```
start   : root+ EOF -> ^(LIST root+ );

root    : expr
        | LPARAM
        | RPARAM
        ;
        
expr    : list
        | atom
        ;           
        
list    : LPARAM expr+ RPARAM -> ^(LIST expr+)
        ;

atom    : INT
        ;
```

Rule `root` matches mismatched `LPARAM`s and `RPARAM`s. Rules `list` and `atom` only care about themselves.

This solution is relatively fragile because rule `root` requires `expr` to be listed before `LPARAM` and `RPARAM`. Even so, maybe this is enough to solve your problem.

#### Test case 1 : no lists

Input: `1 2 3`

Output:

[image: 1 2 3]

#### Test case 2 : one list

Input: `1 (2) 3`

Output:

[image: 1 (2) 3]

#### Test case 3 : two lists

Input: `(1) 2 (3)`

Output:

[image: (1) 2 (3)]

#### Test case 4 : no lists, mismatched lefts

Input: `((1 2 3`

Output:

[image: ((1 2 3]

#### Test case 5 : two lists, mismatched lefts

Input: `((1 (2) (3)`

Output:

[image: ((1 (2) (3)]

#### Test case 6 : no lists, mismatched rights

Input: `1 2 3))`

Output:

[image: 1 2 3))]

#### Test case 7 : two lists, mismatched rights

Input: `(1) (2) 3))`

Output:

[image: (1) (2) 3))]

#### Test case 8 : two lists, mixed mismatched lefts

Input: `((1 (2) ( (3)`

Output:
[image: ((1 (2) ( (3)]

#### Test case 9 : two lists, mixed mismatched rights

Input: `(1) ) (2) 3))`

Output:

[image: (1) ) (2) 3))]

---

Here's a slightly more complicated grammar that operates on `[]` and `()` pairs. I think the solution is going to get exponentially worse as you add pairs, but hey, it's fun! You may also be hitting the limitation of what you can do with grammar-driven AST building.

```
start   : root+ EOF -> ^(LIST root+ )
        ;
        
root    : expr
        | LPARAM
        | RPARAM
        | LSQB
        | RSQB
        ;       
expr    : plist
        | slist
        | atom
        ;           
        
plist   : LPARAM pexpr* RPARAM -> ^(LIST pexpr*)
        ;
        
pexpr   : slist
        | atom
        | LSQB
        | RSQB
        ;       
        
slist   : LSQB sexpr* RSQB -> ^(LIST sexpr*)
        ;
        
sexpr   : plist
        | atom
        | LPARAM
        | RPARAM
        ;               
        
atom    : INT;

INT     : ('0'..'9')+;
LPARAM  : '(';
RPARAM  : ')';
LSQB    : '[';
RSQB    : ']';
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with my problem. I really appreciate all the additional test cases you added. I just changed expr+ to expr*, to allow empty parentheses.

Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Hi, sorry to ask again, but I'm trying to take your answer and apply it to my grammar.

Now LPARAM and RPARAM, are represented by 2 rules called openOp and  closeOp. openOp corresponds to starting operators such as '(', '{', '|' and closeOp to closing operators such as ')', '}', '|'. The rules also return a string called 'op' with the text of the matched token.

Can I use a semantic predicate to check that the two operators can match each other?

list  : l=openOp  expr* r=closeOp  {canBalance($l.op,$r.op)}?-> ^(LIST expr*).

Comment: @DavidJamesBall That's a tough one. In my grammar above, `expr` represents anything that can be contained in a list. That excludes mismatched bits because they're managed by `root`. Allowing one type of mismatch into a valid match (e.g. `([1)` -> `^(LIST [ 1)`) won't work with this approach easily, but I'll give it some more thought.

Comment: I've isolated the problem. Your rules work just fine. The problem is that with my rule...

list : l=openOp expr* r=closeOp {canBalance($l.op,$r.op)}?-> ^(LIST expr*).

Then $l.op and $r.op are always null. If I pass in $l.text instead I can see that openOp is working correctly. If I Remove the predicate then $l.op and $r.op are no longer null. Is there some subtlety of using a semantic predicate at the end of a rule that I'm unaware of. It seems to execute it first or something.

Comment: I think it's because of backtracking: the semantic predicate depends on actions firing in a rule, but those actions aren't hit because the parser is backtracking. If `openOp` and `closeOp` only reference one token per alternative, you can use `$l.start` to grab the token. Otherwise, use `{{$op = $WHATEVER}}` in your rules to force the action to occur, even during backtracking.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about wrapping inside {{...}} to force an action. I misunderstood what you meant about ([1) -> ^(LIST [ 1)) before, yeah I can see it doesn't create the correct tree even if the outer balanced symbols match.

Comment: @DavidJamesBall I updated the answer with a grammar than seems capable of handling two pair types. I haven't tested this thoroughly, but it's basically a scaled-up version of the original grammar. I think we've hit the limit of what this approach can do, and maybe the limit of what grammar-driven AST building can do reasonably. If you want to get more eyeballs on the many-pair-types-and-mismatches-as-tokens problem, consider writing up a new question specifically for it.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's easier to just have the precondition with my project that balancing operators must be properly nested. I'm trying to gather mathematical semantics from some input, and it requires well-formed input, so improper nesting isn't going to be much of an issue I think.